# Does the hull of a spacecraft acquire a charge during its rapid ascent through Earth's atmosphere?

Tags: energy, shielding, capsule

Known fact: [Heat causes a charge to accumulate on the hull of a craft at reentry.](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/91/why-is-it-that-during-reentry-phase-a-capsule-cannot-communicate-with-mission-co)

Questions:

- Does the hull acquire a charge during the course of its *ascent* too?
- What magnitude is this charge? (My guess is it would be a small fraction compared to the charge generated at reentry owing to the velocity difference.)
- How is this charge dissipated?

Comment: You might want to read the story of [Apollo 12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_12#Launch_and_transfer).

Comment: See also: [ITO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indium_tin_oxide).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes.

How do I know that? Well, [multiple](http://www.columbiassacrifice.com/$C_hypersonic.htm) [sources](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/BGH/hihyper.html) say that a layer of 'electrically charged plasma' develops around the ship.

Since the plasma is electrically charged (*highly* charged), some of that charge will be transferred to the hull of the vehicle.

I couldn't find any info on the *amount* of charge generated, but I'm sure it's quite high considering the forces involved.

I found [a paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0906.3884.pdf) on the subject of 'Spacecraft Charging and Hazards to Electronics in Space' - which seems to be exactly what we're looking for. It primarily deals with the effects of this plasma and charges in orbit, but much of the information is relevant to reentry also.

Answer (score 1):

There should be little charge remaining on the rocket body during powered ascent, despite the significant charge generation.

The reason being that the rocket body forms fraction of a percent of the very large conductive body that is passing up through the atmosphere. The vast majority of it is the conductive and neutrally charged plasma exhaust from the engines, which is *many* times the volume of the rocket body.

Effectively, the rocket earths itself out against a very large amount of atmosphere.

Which is part of the reason why one does not launch through lightning-forming clouds. Lightning *loves* to be introduced to a half-a-kilometer or longer conductive rod that gets rammed through a charged cloud!