# Why can't infomation be transmitted during descent?

Tags: spacecraft, communication, reentry, atmosphere

Apparently, no information could pass through plasma, therefore during descent of spacecraft, no information can be transmitted. Why so?

Comment: Related: [Communication Blackout](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/6234/49) and [Why is it that during reentry phase a capsule cannot communicate with mission control?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/91/49)

Comment: @TildalWave I'm curious how this question is different from the second answer you posted.

Comment: @TomSterkenburg None of the two really discuss the reason why plasma causes communications blackout. The second one merely discusses that plasma forms and why. There's a lot to be said about EMI through spurious emissions, electromagnetism of ionized gases, magnetohydrodynamics, and so on associated with reentering vehicles. There's also one myth to bust here. ;) For reference: [Causes and Mitigation of Radio Frequency (RF) Blackout During Reentry of Reusable Launch Vehicles](http://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/ast/reports_studies/media/ATR-2007%285309%29-1.pdf) (PDF)

Comment: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1022559710578

Comment: @mins Why did you delete your answer? It was really good.

Answer (score 3):

Plasma is "electrically neutral medium of unbound positive and negative particles". As it's got charge carriers floating about, it's electically conductive. In a sense, you can think of it as a metal sheet. If a metal sheet fully encloses the spacecraft, you'd get a Faraday Cage. Similarly, if the plasma sheath fully encloses the space craft, you end up with a Faraday Cage. Faraday Cages massively attenuate EM signals attempting to pass through them, resulting in loss of RF communications.